# IBM Worklight - Silent Direct Update vs Regular Direct Update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I came across two types of updates provided by worklight:

1. Silent Direct Update
2. Regular Direct Update

I found the major difference between them is, in silent update user is not notified about the update and in the direct update user is notified about the update.

Is there any other difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other differences between Regular Direct Update to Silent Direct Update. Had there been any, [the documentation would have stated this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_init.html)...

The only difference is as you have written in the question. In Silent Direct Update the user will not see a confirmation dialog to accept the update.

Comment: Silent Direct Update is just like Regular Direct Update. In Direct Update the updating is done on the specific version of the web resources that you have deployed. The same applies to Silent Direct Update.

Comment: Thanks now if have updated the version of my application does that new version be affected in any of my older version.

Comment: You have version 1.0 and version 1.1; If you update the web resources of 1.0, then only 1.0 is updated. 1.1 is not updated. If you update the web resources of 1.1, then only 1.1 is updated. 1.0 is not updated.